# Kubernetes with Cluster Autoscaler & Statefulset: node(s) had volume node affinity conflict

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have an Kubernetes cluster on AWS with Cluster Autoscaler (a component to automically adjusts the desired number of nodes based on usage). The cluster previously had node A on AZ-1 and node B on AZ-2. When I deploy my statefulset with dynamic PVC, the PVC and PV are created on AZ-2, and the pods are created on node B.

I deleted the statefulset to perform some testing. The Cluster Autoscaler decides that one node is now enough and adjusted the desired number down to 1. Now that node B is deleted, when I redeploy my statefulset, the pods are in pending state and can't be created on node A with the following error:

```
Events:
   Type     Reason             Age                   From                Message
   ----     ------             ----                  ----                -------
   Warning  FailedScheduling   2m8s (x997 over 18h)  default-scheduler   0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had volume node affinity conflict.
   Normal   NotTriggerScaleUp  95s (x6511 over 18h)  cluster-autoscaler  pod didn't trigger scale-up: 1 node(s) had volume node affinity conflict
```

I know it is because the PVs are created in AZ-2 and can't be attached to pods in AZ-1, but how do I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple node groups, each scoped to a single Availability Zone. In addition, you should enable the --balance-similar-node-groups feature.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managed-node-groups.html
Important
If you are running a stateful application across multiple Availability Zones that is backed by Amazon EBS volumes and using the Kubernetes Cluster Autoscaler, you should configure multiple node groups, each scoped to a single Availability Zone. In addition, you should enable the --balance-similar-node-groups feature.